# Filter List or Lists based on the inner lists in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

I wanted to filter a list of lists using rxJava and arrived at the following solution. But I am using Observable.toBlocking() at a couple of places. Can I do it more elegantly.

For the sake of the question I have created a list of list where inner is contains range of integers say (1 - 10, 10 - 20) and outer list contains all these lists. And I want filter the list on the basis of terms in the inner list so I pass a collection searchList such that if the inner list contains any of the elements from the searchList I want to keep it.

My Solution:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> longFuncReturnList(Iterable<List<Integer>> masterIterable, List<Integer> searchList) {

    return Observable.from(masterIterable)
    .filter(new Func1<List<Integer>, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(List<Integer> t1) {


            Observable<Boolean> result = Observable.from(new IteratorIterable<Integer>(t1.iterator()))
                    .exists(new Func1<Integer, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Integer t1) {

                    return searchList.contains(t1); 
                }
            });
            return result.toBlocking().first();
        }
    }).toList().toBlocking().single();

}
```

And to this I pass a List of List using the following method:

```
Iterable<List<Integer>> masterIterable = new IteratorIterable<List<Integer>>(masterList.iterator());
    longFuncReturnList(masterIterable);
```

masterList is my List of List.

For filtering I use Observable.exists() but since it returns another observable I use toBlocking().first() to get the boolean result.

Is my solution correct in a Rx way?
How can I make it better?

Comment: Taking into account the signature of the function, I think it's supposed to be synchronous. Why do you even need RxJava then?

Comment: I was trying out RxJava for reading data from excel sheets. Since I have large sheets with lots of data I thouught RxJava would be helpful. I had multiple scenarios where I had to filter out rows based on cell data. This implementation was for testing.